# SQL select group of records

Tags: sql

Is there a faster way to write the following query on a table called OrderDtl?

```
OrderId Product
1       ORANGE
1       APPLE
2       SHAMPOO
2       SOAP
2       TOOTHPASTE
```

---

```
SELECT *
FROM OrderDtl
WHERE OrderId in
    (
        SELECT OrderId
        FROM OrderDtl
        WHERE Product='APPLE'
    )
```

---

Which results in

```
1       ORANGE
1       APPLE
```

Comment: What is 'faster' depends on which DBMS you're using, indexes, size and structure of the table, and other factors.  Your best bet, in my opinion, is to create a dummy set of data, of a size representative of your live environment, and start testing alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Join the table to itself.

After seeing the comment from Dems I changed the SQL to add a couple of indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE #OrderDtl (OrderId INT, Product CHAR(10))

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Order ON #OrderDtl (OrderId) 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Order_Product ON #OrderDtl (Product) INCLUDE (OrderId)

INSERT #OrderDtl SELECT 1, 'ORANGE'
INSERT #OrderDtl SELECT 1, 'APPLE'
INSERT #OrderDtl SELECT 2, 'SHAMPOO'
INSERT #OrderDtl SELECT 2, 'SOAP'
INSERT #OrderDtl SELECT 2, 'TOOTHPASTE'

SELECT T2.* 
FROM #OrderDtl T1 INNER JOIN #OrderDtl T2
ON T1.OrderId = T2.OrderId
WHERE T1.Product='APPLE'

SELECT *
FROM #OrderDtl
WHERE OrderId in
    (
        SELECT OrderId
        FROM #OrderDtl
        WHERE Product='APPLE'
    )
```

Comparing the resulting execution plans is interesting, for this trivial example the result is the same:

[image: Execution plan]

**EDIT:** 
Adding the execution plan of esastincy answer, it's the same again in execution "effort"

[image: Additional execution plan]

You may also be interested in this article: [SQL Server: JOIN vs IN vs EXISTS - the logical difference](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx)

Comment: Although the execution plan for esastincy query shows as 5% cost in the batch all the other queries showed the same value, I just didn't want to have to replace all the images.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ord2.* 
FROM OrderDtl ord1 INNER JOIN OrderDt1 ord2
  ON ord1.Product = 'APPLE' AND ord2.OrderId = ord1.OrderId
```